# How to determine from where scroll event is raised?

Tags: javascript, html

i have problem, let suppose there is a div DIV1, in which the overflow attribute is set to auto. 
there is another div DIV2 inside the DIV1, which is draggable.

Now i have to perform different operations/calculation on the behalf of the scrolling. 
i have attached a event Listener for the scroll event of DIV1 but the event is raising every time, either i will drag the Div2 more than DIV1 current height/width or if i will scroll using the scroll bar of DIV1.

So my question is "how can i differentiate between these element's event" ?

Comment: Post your code, would help in resolution.

Comment: Maybe you could stop listening to the scroll event while dragging ?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle.net replicating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

stop listening to the scroll event while dragging